# Why is my span element not appearing onto my header?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to draw additional (mock) buttons onto my page with plain CSS, but my `span` element is not showing up. I've tried giving it a `display: block;` and I've also tried positioning it absolutely, but nothing seems to work. And out of those two ways, which is the preferred/most clear method?

```css
header {
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   border-bottom: 6px solid black;
   padding: 15px 0 10px 0;
}

   img {
     width: 43px;
     height: 43px;
   }

   .red-button {
     background: yellow;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
   }
 

 header:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 74px; 
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 6px solid maroon;
 }

 header:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   border-bottom: 6px solid $light-red;
 }
```

```html
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="./assets/pokeball.svg" alt="pokedex">
      <span className="red-button"></span>
    </header>
  </body>
```

Comment: Are you trying to render plain css with "className" instead of "class"?

Comment: Two questions:
1. You used `className` instead of `class`. Are you rendering a JSX? If not, switching to `class` might be a good start.
1. I see that you are nesting a couple elements. Are you using SCSS/LESS or/and CSS-in-JS solutions? If not, trying to write out each nested element might be another starting point.

Comment: Ah I'm actually using a `scss` file and yes, I am rendering JSX!

Answer (score 1):

Just try to replace `className` by `class`.

Comment: Good job. A little explanation wont hurt anybody.

Comment: When you are working with html and css, and need to define a style that will be reusable, this is a `class`. The term `className` is used when working with React.JS, e.g.